# writing backup program in python

Tags: python

I found this tutorial in A Byte of Python, but do not understand it:

```
import os
import time

source = [r'C:\Users\Desktop\Stuff']

target_dir = 'C:\Users\Backup'

target = target_dir + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

zip_command = 'zip -qr "%s" %s' % (target, ' '.join(source))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print 'Successful backup to', target
else:
    print 'Backup failed!'
```

After checking `help(os)` I do not understand why `os.system(zip_command)` would ever be zero. `.system()` does not return a Boolean, does it?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`help(os.system)` says:

```
system(...)
    system(command) -> exit_status

    Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.
```

So, it executes the `command` you pass as a parameter and returns the `exit_status` of that command.

When a program returns `0` as result, it means it was executed succesfully and if it returns anything else, it probably means there was an error somewhere.

So in this line:

```
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
```

you are actually asking: *if the command line was executed succesfully then ... else ...*

Comment: Also worth reading is the [online Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) which explains `os.system` in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the return value is that returned by the system shell after running command, given by the Windows environment variable COMSPEC: on command.com systems (Windows 95, 98 and ME) this is always 0; on cmd.exe systems (Windows NT, 2000 and XP) this is the exit status of the command run; on systems using a non-native shell, consult your shell documentation.
see [this](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system).

Answer (score 0):

The os.system(command) runs a command in a subshell, and returns an int.

Taken from python docs:

*"On Windows, the return value is that returned by the system shell after running command, given by the Windows environment variable COMSPEC: on command.com systems (Windows 95, 98 and ME) this is always 0; on cmd.exe systems (Windows NT, 2000 and XP) this is the exit status of the command run; on systems using a non-native shell, consult your shell documentation."*

So it returns 0 if the command was successful, and something else if it wasn't.

Source: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system